# .Net Framework on Unix

Tags: .net, unix

Can .net applications run on unix or we can run them purely in windows servers? Any explanation would be appreciated

Comment: Looking at [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) would be a good starting point. You can then come back and ask some more targeted questions.

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MONO-Project is what you are searching for, URL is http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page.
Depending on your requirements, a bit of recoding is required, especially in the UI.